# how to insert multiple entries to postgres using spring, JPARepository

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

Like I have an ArrayList,
Then I call my repo from service, somewhat like

```
userRepository.insertUsers(userArrayList);
```

and here i have my repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

@Transactional
@Modifying()
@Query("INSERT INTO usermaster ..........")
    public int insertUsers(@Param("userArrayList") List<User> userArrayList);

}
```

**all I need is a query to bulk insert this ArrayList above**, I couldn't find an answer for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried with the default method `save`? like this: `userRepository.save(userArrayList);`

Comment: You don't need a `@Repository` annotation when you implement on of Spring Datas repository interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need custom method, JpaRepository has save method which accepts list of your entity, this will be enough

```
userRepository.save(userArrayList);
```